# Data.Function.Memoize missing from ghci on mac?

Tags: macos, haskell, ghci

I'm trying to import memoize2 in ghci on my mac:

```
Prelude Data.Function> import Data.Function.Memoize (memoize2)

<no location info>:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Function.Memoize’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

This is my ghci version, latest available on brew.

```
$ ghci --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3
```

The memoization library seems to be in the `Haskell98` stdlib.

Comment: Nope, it's in the [memoize](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memoize-0.7) package.

Comment: in cases like this [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=memoize2) is your friend (Hoogle will not find it)

Comment: Strictly speaking haskell 98 doesn't even support hierarchical names, so any module which uses a dotted name on import cannot be part of the Haksell98 stdlib because it *isn't* valid Haskell98. Moreover the stdlib is really small, see [the report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/)... it has 16 modules only.  Haskell 2010 supports hierarchical names, as you can see [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellpa2.html#x20-192000II) but it's stdlib is still extremely small (30 modules).